# Pydoc is not recognized as a command in the windows command line

Tags: python, pydoc

I am trying to check the documentation for Math module in the command line of windows. However, I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Farhan Hasant\Desktop\HelloWorld>pydoc math
'pydoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your favorite python to the PATH, or assume this is already done.

Run

```
python -m pydoc math
```